# Saving Thunderbird attachments directly into Google Drive

Tags: thunderbird, google-drive

I would like to know if there is any add-on (or any hack) to be able to save Thunderbird attachments directly into Google Drive.

Ideally, a right-click on the file and the option "Upload to Google Drive". Or something like that.

That'd be pretty awesome...

Comment: Uh...Google Drive creates a folder on your hard drive. Why not just set Thunderbird to use that as your default save location?

Comment: I can't install the GDrive software on my computer... (no admin rights). Also (IN A VERY IDEAL WORLD) I would like the operation to happen without me downloading first, then reuploading it to Google Drive.

Comment: This is a pretty old question, but you might try looking at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or posting there for this type of recommendation.